# Allow all users to view all groups (private or public) with Organic groups, but not private content

Tags: users, organic-groups

I am using [Drupal 7.25](https://drupal.org/drupal-7.25) (I need to update to 7.26) and [organic groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) 7.x-2.4.  I currently have public and private groups working.  I have two users (admin and a normal user).  I have a menu tab that opens the og list (/og-list) view which I want to list all groups (public or private)

Currently all public groups show up for the normal user.  The private groups are still not shown in this list to the normal user.  If I log in as admin they see all private and public groups.

How can I make private groups show up in this list to all users?  When they click on the group they shouldn't be able to view the content, just the group name and a subscription link.  If I type in the direct link to the group is gives me an an Access is denied page.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List Private Organic Groups Publicly without giving access to the node page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/827/list-private-organic-groups-publicly-without-giving-access-to-the-node-page?rq=1)
That post answered my question.  Thanks [Damien Tournoud](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/503/damien-tournoud) for posting the following answer:

> You can tell Views to ignore the access control of some of the Views.
>   On Views 3.x, this parameter can be found under "Query Settings" /
>   "Disable SQL rewriting", and is described as:
>
> Disabling SQL rewriting will disable node_access checks as well as
>   other modules that implement hook_db_rewrite_sql(). The full nodes
>   will stay private, so you should make sure not to link to them in the
>   View so that your users do not land on "Access Denied" (403) pages.