# Display a View of Private Organic Groups for 'Requesting Access'

Tags: views, organic-groups

Right now I have it set up so groups are 'Private' in OG 7.2.x on D7

When using og_extras there is a view that lists the 'Groups'. However, when they are set to private, because the og permissions module is enabled, the groups do not show when an anonymous user acceses the page.

With the correct permissions, non-members can request access to groups, and a URL like this will let users join a Private Group:

example.org/group/node/6469/subscribe

Now, the BIG QUESTION:

How can I get views to show the Group name, Group Description, 'Private', and 'Request Access links' in a public facing view, yet have the content/members of the group be private?

It seems like the idea of a 'Private Group' is that people can't even see the name of it. That assumption is irrelevant to my site, I just want them to not be able to access the groups homepage/content unless they are members, I want them to see the groups they 'could be a part of'.

Thanks! And apologies if this was too indirect.

Comment: Zach this is exactly what I need to do right now. Can't believe you just asked this question. I will follow this closely and do anything I can to help. Did you look at this one I just found on the sidebar: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/827/list-private-organic-groups-publicly-without-giving-access-to-the-node-page?rq=1

Comment: See below - worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: edit the OG Extras Group view and do the following. Answer taken from here:https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/865/2957

---

You can tell Views to ignore the access control of some of the Views. On Views 3.x, this parameter can be found under "Query Settings" / "Disable SQL rewriting", and is described as:

> Disabling SQL rewriting will disable node_access checks as well as
>   other modules that implement hook_db_rewrite_sql().

The full nodes will stay private, so you should make sure not to link to them in the View so that your users do not land on "Access Denied" (403) pages.